# To have multiple nine-patch images or just one? If one, where to put it?

Tags: android, android-layout, nine-patch

So far, I always created one nine-patch image and place it inside `/res/drawable-hdpi`.

But I saw some large projects which have multiple nine-page images, scaled and placed inside multiple `res/drawable-xxx` directories. Is this the wrong approach? Nine-patch was supposed to stretch across all screens, regardless of its DPI.

Also, if I am right and only one nine-patch is to be used, what is its default location - `drawable-hdpi`, `mdpi`, or some other directory inside `/res`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it really depends on **quality**.

If your image is just a **square border**, it can be a 72 dpi low res image put into the drawable folder and it would be **enough**.

If your image has **rounded corners** or other fancy elements that have to be scaled properly, you **could** make a 480 dpi version and put it in the drawable-xxhdpi folder. This will scale down (don't even think of scaling up, because of stretching/pixellating) **good enough** in most cases.

If you want the **best quality** in scaling, then make a version for each dpi drawable folder.

If you go to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html, you can see it there (citation):

> **file location:**
>       res/drawable/filename.9.png
>       The filename is used as the resource ID.

Comment: When you said "72dpi...put into the drawable folder", did you refer to `/res/drawable` or some `res/drawable-xxx`directory? I am asking because we should keep XMLs only in `/res/drawable/`

Comment: I mean `/res/drawable` - there you can put the "common graphics" too (as an alternative, use the `/res/drawable-mdpi` if you only want xmls in `/res/drawable`). mdpi is the "normal" unit (160 dpi) and 1px = 1dp for mdpi resources

Comment: In `res/drawable` there must NOT be anything but XML drawables. That is the rule and I suggest you fix your practice accordingly. Otherwise you may experience strange error on `xhdpi` and larger devices, like run out of memory, crashes "cannot find resource", etc.

Comment: If so, use `/res/drawable-mdpi`... but I'm not sure of what you are saying: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Comment: I thought you're talking about images in general when you suggested I place them in `res/drawable`. But you were referring to nine-patch only? If so, you are absolutely right. I read it on the link you posted. Sorry for misunderstanding you :).

Comment: No need to feel sorry. Maybe sometimes I don't express myself too clearly. ;)